fmt_image() conflicting with opt_interactive() when deployed
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    gt_output("dog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$dog = render_gt({
        data.frame(
            Animal = c("Cat", "Dog"),
            URL = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg/1200px-Cat_August_2010-4.jpg", "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg")) %>%
                gt() %>%
                fmt_image(URL, height = 50) %>%
                opt_interactive()
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Above is a basic shiny app that I've made to reproduce this issue. Basically, when I use fmt_image() with opt_interactive(), and deploy the app, the table fails to render. It does not display an error message either.
The logs on the shiny app don't display any errors either, which is puzzling.
The app works perfectly fine when run locally in RStudio.

This question is similar to: fmt_image() conflicting with opt_interactive(). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Same author here. This post is a better articulation of the problem I'm facing. The past, similar post has been deleted

You may want to update the reactR package to 0.6.1 https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1835

If this doesn't work, maybe trying the dev version of gt may help pak::pak("rstudio/gt")
